# pykd can not start thread use threading in python script

Tags: windows, windbg, pykd

when I use threading.Thread to create new thread.it can not start. The code like this

```
import threading
import time
import sys
def worker():
    count = 1
    while True:
        if count >= 6:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1
        print("thread name = {}, thread id = {}".format(threading.current_thread().name,threading.current_thread().ident))
 
t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker,name="t1")
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker,name='t2')
 
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

When I run this code. The windbg will not report error 、not print any thing and never return
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3NLO.png)

I will to create new thread to run something

Comment: A for loop would be more appropriate than this `while True:`  loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 'threading' within windbg. Windbg has own multithreading model and loop of debug events. It is near impossible to run all this threads together without bugs.

In fact I dont't recomend to use 'threading' also in standalone python program with pykd module. All my scripts always use 'multiprocessing' module.